# Trying to exlude certain sheets from a VBA Worksheet Loop

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have the below code, but when I run the macro, it seems to ignore the fact that I've excluded the "Input" sheet. Any ideas?
I'm aware there are probably other errors in the preceding code, but I'd like to fix this first!

```
Sub export_all()
Dim Path As String
Dim Name As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Path = Workbooks("CGL Configurator V3.xlsm").Sheets("Input").Range("$C$12")
Name = ActiveSheet.Range("A151")
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Input" Then
        Range("A1:AZ151").Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & "\" & Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8
        Range("A151").Delete
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If
Next ws
Workbooks("CGL Configurator V3.xlsm").Sheets("Input").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: What is it? Does it ignore your exclusion, or does it only *seem to ignore* it? The first thing I'd try is to set a breakpoint on the `If` statement, and then step through your code (F8) to see whats going on. Alternatively, add `Debug.Print(ws.Name)` inside that `If` statement.

Comment: +1 for `debug.print ws.Name` on the next line, before `Range("A1:AZ151").Copy`. Alternatively, use an `Else If ws.Name = "Input" then End If`

Comment: Thanks @Berend, F8 was useful, turns out I was missing a '.ws' before Range("A1:AZ151").Copy, so it was missing the Input sheet, but then copying cells off it anyway as it was the active sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I was missing a '.ws' before Range("A1:AZ151").Copy, so it was missing the Input sheet, but then copying cells off it anyway as it was the active sheet.